# Link-to helper using active class inside nested view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a View that triggers a dropdown. Inside of that view is another view, the dropdown itself. I'm using an "active" class binding and CSS to show and hide the dropdown. Code:

**DropdownLinkView.js:**

```
var DropdownLinkView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ['dropdown-trigger'],
  classNameBindings: ['active'],
  active: false,
  mouseEnter: function(evt) {
    this.set('active', true);
  },
  mouseLeave: function(evt) {
    this.set('active', false);
  },
  dropdownView: Ember.View.extend({
    mouseLeave: function(evt) {
      var dropdown;
      dropdown = $(evt.target).parents('.nav-dropdown').data('dropdown-target');
      if ($(evt.toElement).hasClass(dropdown)) {
        return;
      }
      this.set('active', false);
    }
  })
});
```

**header-navigation.hbs:**

```
{{#view DropdownLinkView}}
  <div class="nav-link">
    <span>Hover Over Me!</span>
    {{#view view.dropdownView}}
      <div class="nav-dropdown">
        {{#each item in items}}
          {{#link-to "item" item class="nav-dropdown-item"}}
            <span class="nav-dropdown-item-name">
              {{item.name}}
            </span>
          {{/link-to}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    {{/view}}
  </div>
{{/view}}
```

When I click a link inside of the `view.DropdownView`, I'd like to close the dropdown, therefore my instinct is to set `active` to `false` in the DropdownLinkView. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that from clicking the link. Any ideas?

Comment: An [ember.jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com) is always nice!

Comment: Plus, not every Ember developer knows coffee script, target the bigger audience ;)

Comment: Thanks @givanse I updated it to JS. I'll try creating a ember.jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a component view and define a component handler to close/hide the component:

```
App.DropdownLinkComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  classNameBindings: ['isHidden'],
  isHidden: false,

  actions: {

    close: function() {

      console.log('close component with CSS classNameBindings');
      this.set('isHidden', true);

    }

  }


});
```

Then, you could trigger the action inside your component as:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/dropdown-link">
    <div {{action 'close' on='mouseLeave'}}>
    child content
    </div>
  </script>
```

Note: you could show/hide the component with CSS :hover instead of defining your handler on `mouseEnter` and `mouseLeave`.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zodon/1/edit